# Constructing an orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

### For some $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^n$, show that there exist an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{O}$ such that $\mathbf{Ox}=(\lVert \mathbf{x} \rVert,0,...,0)$.

Hello. I see some basic result of $L^1$ Frourier transform. It said if a function is radial, then it's Fourier transform is also radial.
To show this result, they assuming there is an orthogonal matrix $\mathbf{O}$.

I can't imagine this matrix. 
I think the matrix relation doesn't hold for all element in n-dimensional space.
Instead, it just holds for each specific elements.


So my trying is below. 
First, projection the element in first linear space.
Second, multiply some constant, so that the one dimensional vector has the norm of x.

However, with this method rank of matrix is broken, so that it is not orthogonal matrix.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a [Householder matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation).

Comment: @J. M. is not a mathematician   Nice Idea. Instead of looking projection, find a hyperplan and reflect it. I didn't think like that before. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:
Use Gram-Schmidt (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) on the basis $(x,e_2,\ldots,e_n)$ to obtain an orthonormal basis $(b_1:=\frac{x}{\|x\|},b_2,\ldots,b_n)$. Now the Inverse of the Matrix given by the linear map by
$$e_j\mapsto b_j, j=1,\ldots,n$$
should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. I learned a lot. In this method, there are lot of matrix because we can make different bj. How about this? If we choose x0, which is very near to x. but it doesn't give x0 norm. If we definie such a thing as stability, Is there a basis that assure the stability? i.e. choose the basis that reducing other components.

Comment: Yes of course, Gram-Schmidt only consists of continuous operations in $x$, so the given process already gives you your desired continuity properties.

Answer (score 0):

Given two orthonormal bases $\{ e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ and $\{f_1, \cdots, f_n\}$ the change of basis matrix $T$ that takes $e_i$ to $f_i$ is orthogonal. Extend the unit vector $\frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}$ to an orthonormal basis say $\{ f_1 = \frac{x}{\Vert x\Vert}, f_2, \cdots, f_n \}$. Then taking $\{ e_1, \cdots, e_n\}$ to be the standard basis, the change of basis matrix taking $e_i$ to $f_i$ sends the vector $x$ to $(\Vert x \Vert, 0, \cdots, 0)$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand just before. So the basic Idea is decompose a vector in two products. Scalar parts and Vector Parts. i.e. x=norm(x)*(unit vector of x).  And If we choose x direction as basis direction, then it's norm appear.

Comment: That's right. <>